# Chart.js tooltip yAlign

Tags: javascript, tooltip, chart.js

Tooltip don't want be at the bottom.
I tried:

```
  Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.yAlign = 'bottom';
```

and

```
 options = {
     tooltips: {
          yAlign: 'bottom'
     },
```

Did not help

[image: result]

Comment: I think this option applies only for the caret (arrow) and not for the tooltip position itself

Answer (score 0):

It is works fine! But counting is from the top face of the bar!